# How to always show the code preview widget that appears at the bottom of the suggestion widget?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The snippet suggestions widget has this small panel at the bottom of it that previews the code contained in the snippet:
[image: |300]

On my Code it will sometimes show and other times it will not. Is there a setting to make sure it is always shown or at least a hotkey that I can use to show it with?

I thought the setting `editor.suggest.preview` was it but if I set it to `false` the preview widget still shows up, so it must be for something else

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but you should find your answer in my answer post there

Comment: @starball, Hey are you reffering to this `editor.suggest.showInlineDetails` setting in your linked to answer? I tested it with bool value of `true` but still I am not getting that second widget on the bottom.

Comment: no, I'm saying that if the extension doesn't provide the details / documentation fields for  a suggestion, then you're not going to get a suggestions details panel for the suggestion.

Comment: @starball, okay now I understand you and I think we are talking about two different things. I am refering to  the widget that is shown at bottom of the suggestion widget (refer to the above screenshot). Its meant to preview the code for the highlighted user/non-user snippets. Whereas you are refering to the grayed out text shown to the right of every snippet.

Comment: no, I am in fact talking about the same thing as you. the dup target I closed this as a duplicate of is indeed talking about the inline details, but basically the same information in my answer post there applies here.

Comment: @starball I see, very well then. Thank you for the help :)